# Can I access method bodies (e.g. IL byte array) using Assembly.TryGetRawMetadata and System.Reflection.Metadata?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, metadata

.NET Core 2's FCL includes an extension method [`Assembly.TryGetRawMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.assemblyextensions.trygetrawmetadata) which one can use to inspect a loaded assembly's metadata using [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata).

I'd like to use these facilities to inspect method bodies (like I would with regular Reflection's [`MethodBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbody)), but that doesn't appear to be possible.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;

class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        if (thisAssembly.TryGetRawMetadata(out byte* rawMetadata, out int rawMetadataLength) == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        var metadata = new MetadataReader(rawMetadata, rawMetadataLength);

        foreach (var methodDefinitionHandle in metadata.MethodDefinitions)
        {
            var methodDefinition = metadata.GetMethodDefinition(methodDefinitionHandle);
            var methodRVA = methodDefinition.RelativeVirtualAddress;
            … // Question: Is there any way to get to the method body from `methodRVA`? 
        }
    }
}
```

I can get at methods' RVAs, but since I have no way of finding out what RVA the `rawMetadata` pointer corresponds to, I appear to have no way of dereferencing these RVAs.

AFAIK, [`Assembly.TryGetRawMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.assemblyextensions.trygetrawmetadata) returns only a data blob starting at the metadata root (`BSJB`) and including the metadata streams and heaps, but method bodies are actually stored outside of this data.

Of course I could just start by inspecting the whole assembly file (whose path is given in `thisAssembly.Location`), but that would require re-loading it into memory a second time.

Does [`Assembly.TryGetRawMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.assemblyextensions.trygetrawmetadata) really not allow me to get at the method bodies, or am I overlooking something?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not possible to do that exactly as you would like with `TryGetRawMetadata`. As specification states, "Method bodies can be stored in any read-only section of a PE file", and so metadata blob alone is not enough to resolve that RVA. You have to use `PEReader` like this:

```
static void Main() {
    var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (var asmFile = File.OpenRead(thisAssembly.Location)) {
        var reader = new PEReader(asmFile);
        var metadata = reader.GetMetadataReader();

        foreach (var methodDefinitionHandle in metadata.MethodDefinitions) {
            var methodDefinition = metadata.GetMethodDefinition(methodDefinitionHandle);
            var methodRVA = methodDefinition.RelativeVirtualAddress;
            // now with PEReader you can resolve your RVA
            var body = reader.GetMethodBody(methodRVA);
            var ilReader = body.GetILReader();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

To make it work as you would like - there should be some analog to `TryGetRawMetadata` which returns pointer and length of whole PE image. `PEReader` already has constructor which accepts such pointer and length, and such analog method (`TryGetRawImage`) has already been proposed as far as I know, but not yet implemented.

That said, `PEReader` will not necessary read whole assembly file into memory. It accepts stream, and has `PEStreamOptions` argument to constructor. Those options include `PrefetchImage`, `PrefetchMetadata` (among others), which suggests that by default it does not read the whole thing into memory.

As an option - you can use `TryGetRawMetadata` to get RVA, and then separately use `PEReader` to resolve it to method body. There is a chance that `PEReader` will then read minimum amount necessary to resolve that RVA and then will seek directly to body and read only that, though I'm not completely sure in that.

If you are brave enough - you can even try to find start of PE image from metadata root pointer yourself, and then feed that into `PEReader` constructor, though I obviously won't recommend that.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this isn't currently possible, and the ideas about `PEReader`!

Comment: Re: _"analog method (`TryGetRawImage`) has already been proposed as far as I know, but not yet implemented."_ Are you referring to [dotnet/corefx#2768](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2768)?

Comment: @stakx I'm not really sure where I saw that, maybe indeed in that issue. For example one comment states "We should have a separate method TryGetPEImage to retrieve the PE image". Not sure if that counts as proposal or not.

Comment: Yes, I saw that sentence, too. I just asked them about any plans they might have about such a method.

Comment: @stakx I'd not expect them to add it anytime soon though. As you can see from that issue, they had a strong reason for TryGetRawMetadata (Roslyn Scripting), but they don't have such strong reason for TryGetRawImage (plus it requires changes to unmanaged parts of coreclr, which gives it even less chance).